# Velocity template substring issue

Tags: java, velocity

I have an issue with extracting a substring in velocity.
the string I have is 1M/1Y (the variable string here)
I need to extract 1M and 1Y.
what is the best way to do it?

```
#set($index=$string.index('/'))
#set($val=$string.substring($index,index+2))
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In velocity template we have access to all the public methods of the String class.
Try using the below code

```
#set ($index = $string.indexOf('/'))
#set ($val1= $string.substring(0, $index))
#set ($index = $index + 1)
#set ($val2 = $string.substring($index))
```

or you can also make use of `$string.split("/")` if you are using Velocity 1.7

Answer (score 1):

You can use stringUtil:

```
#set($parts = $stringUtil.split($string, "/"))
$parts.get(1)
$parts.get(2)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed $ before the last 'index' variable, this should fix your code:

```
#set($index=$string.index('/'))
#set($val=$string.substring($index,$index+2))
```